# react native IOS setInterval NOT RUNNING when proximityMonitoringEnabled

Tags: ios, react-native, setinterval

I am developing audio call screen with [incallmanager library](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager)
When joined call, I called InCallManager.start() => the library when listen to promixity for normal call.

The problem is, I have the interval to set callTime when call connected like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('newcallstate', callState, intervalRef.current)
        if (callState == CALL_STATE.CONNECTED && isVideo === false) {
            if(!intervalRef.current){
                console.log('setinterval now')
                intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
                    setCallTime(prev => {
                        console.log('interval => ', prev + 1)
                        return prev + 1
                    })
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
    }, [callState])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('calltime', callTime)
    }, [callTime])
```

Everything work normally unless when the screen turn black, I do not see any log about ***calltime**** and ***interval =>*** anymore

Can someone give me some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this proble using BackgroundTimer